# Downloading raw PDF from POST request response

Tags: reactjs, react-native, http, post, axios

I'm trying to generate a file from response data. The endpoint I'm hitting returns raw data like this:
%PDF-1.7
%����
6 0 obj
...
And it works fine with postman (I simply download the data as a pdf and its a valid file).
However when I make the same post request from my react native app using axios the data that I receive as a response is just the end of the pdf file. (last 20-30 lines of raw data instead of the whole pdf).

```
axios.post(url, formData)
        .then(res => {
             console.log('RECEIVED RESPONSE:', res.data) //THIS DATA IS JUST THE END OF THE PDF FILE 


             RNFS.writeFile(path, res.data,'utf8')
                .then(result => {
                   
                    dispatch({ type: 'FileCreated', payload: path })
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.error('ERROR WHILE WRITING NEW FILE:', err)
                })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('Caught error while uploading article', err)
        })
```

There are no errors and the file is created but it's corrupted because res.data is not the whole file.

Any ideas why this is happening?